# When I am running My Service Registry using Eureka. I am not getting A Replica URL, Rather I am getting The replica size seems to be empty

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

This is my application.properties:-

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=SERVICE-REGISTRY
#disbale as client
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

This is my pom.xml Where I have added Spring-Web and Netflix eureka client as a dependency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.registry</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceRegistry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ServiceRegistry</name>
    <description>Question Microservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And instead of getting a Replica Node URL: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
I am getting :- c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes: The replica size seems to be empty. Check the route 53 DNS Registry

Comment: That's not the client dependency, but the server